# When can a function be approximated as piecewise constant

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, continuity, approximation

When is it allowed to approximate a (real) function as piecewise constant? Is it enough that it is continuous and differentiable?

Edit: I was downvoted for not providing an example, so here is one: I want to solve an ordinary differential equation (differentiated in $x$) with respect to a function $f(x)$, but the equations include terms $g(x)$ (that are not differentiated). If I assume that $g(x)$ is piecewise constant (i.e. on a discrete lattice), then the solution to the equation simplifies tremendously, and I can even find an analytic solution (where I have to apply boundary conditions at the boundaries in each cell where $g(x)$ is constant). My question is if this approach is generally valid, i.e. when it is reasonable to assume that I can approximate $g(x)$ as piecewise constant.

Comment: You can always approximate a function by a piecewise constant function. Indeed, you can always approximate a function by the zero function. But I suspect there's something you want your approximation to do, that you aren't telling us.

Comment: I guess that the question is under which conditions refining the decomposition gives better and better approximations of the function. In this case, a piecewise continous function is already enough.

Comment: @Peter, yes, most likely that's what's wanted. Although it raises the question of what makes one approximation better than another – there are many different ways to make that precise. And then maybe the question is what conditions on the function allow for arbitrarily good piecewise approximations. Maybe OP will come back to tell us.

Comment: So I'm downvoted for not knowing that the answer to my question is trivial (i.e. that it is always possible for any function and there are no exceptions)? In any case, I have provided an example.

Comment: No, fromGiants, you were invited to clarify your question, that's all. The original question seemed to be, what conditions on $g$ guarantee the existence of piecewise constant approximants, but now it looks like your question is actually, in what kinds of problem can you get the right answer by using piecewise constant approximants. I'm still not completely certain that I catch your drift, though – am I on the right track?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I think you got me right the first time. Let me put it this way instead: say I have solved a one-dimensional ODE (example: $\partial_x f(x) = g(x)*f^n(x) + C$) where I assume that one of the functions that enter the equation ($g(x)$ in this case) is piecewise constant. Then someone asks me if the solution completely breaks down when $g(x)$ is no longer a piecewise step function, but rather a continuous function, like $g(x) = \tanh(x)$. The answer is probably that any "nice" function (or as you claim any function) can be approximated this way for small enough steps.